# Finding n set coprime lying in range 1 to m

Tags: java

Recently i got a coding question in which we have to find number of groups of length n such that adjacent numbers are co-primes given the range of co-primes in between 1 to m.

For Example
Input 1: m =3 and n=1
Output 1: 3 
Following Groups
{1} {2} {3}

Input 2: m=3 and n=2
Output 2: 7
Following Groups
{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,3},{3,2},{2,1},{3,1}

As {2,2} will be out of this case.
Any hints will be appreciated.

I was able to find all the co-primes pairs in the given range.

Comment: Try every combination and test if it's coprime(see http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/Coprime.aspx)

Comment: If n was fixed then checking every combination would have made sense. But as the value of n is variable. The complexity would increase exponentially.

Comment: This does not seem to be a java problem, or even a programming problem. Maybe would want to ask in https://cs.stackexchange.com ?

Comment: @tkruse Got it in interview bit hiring challenge.

Comment: Consider this recommendation: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165519